# How do I validate against values in a database when ID number is submitted on html form?

Tags: html, validation, asp-classic

I already have the .asp document to be displayed when the ID is found on database. It works fine. However, when entering ID numbers not found on the database the .asp document will still open instead of displaying an error message.

```
<form action="http://localhost/teg/f1.asp" method="GET">
<label for="name">ID NUMBER</label>
<input type="number" id="name" name="ID" placeholder="PLEASE ENTER ID" />
<button type="submit">SEND</button>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Can you please include code in your question, instead of linking to a screenshot of it?

Comment: Can you at least show your code for `f1.asp` *(use a formatted code block, not an image like you did before...see the edits to your question)*?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to answer this question if you displayed the code of the page which is receiving the form submission, however a standard way of doing this is to check for an empty recordset and use a conditional statement as follows.

```
rssql = "select * from your_table where ID = " & Cint(Request("ID"))
rs.Open rs_sql,conn
If (rs.bof and rs.eof) then
    'error message goes here
Else
    'code to display record goes here
End if
```

NB: `conn` and `rs` are `ADODB.Connection` and `ADODB.Recordset` objects respectively.  I'm assuming you know what these are and how to create them.

Using `Cint` in this context is a simple means of guarding against a SQL injection attack when you know that the submitted value should be numeric